# Detect and Track Circular/Spherical Particles using Hough Transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have a video recording the flow of spherical particles. My goal is to detect and track those particles to count the number of particles passing through a horizontal line at a given time (For example, at t = 1s, 4 particles; at t = 7s, 50 particles).

See the original video here: [Original recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jqH4-haTSj1_3_AR190OQykl2DMAU8GP/view?usp=sharing)

So I am using Hough Transform to detect the particles frame by frame. It detects the spheres reasonably well even though some blurred particles hiding behind were ignored (any help in this part is greatly appreciated!)

See the output here [Output recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EviD8S4lWbtJ8qfcTHo8q0l9pIAB-eSX/view?usp=sharing)

What I envision is something like this:
[Output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAfaN.jpg)

But I'm not sure how to keep tracking and count the particles once I detect them because you can see in the video that the detection flickers quite a lot between frames, so I am stuck in this part.

Any ideas to help me with this? Cheers everyone.

The code to run:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Parameters
threshold_value = 100
kernel_size = 5

# Read the video
video = cv2.VideoCapture('original-video.mp4')

# Get video properties
width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Create a background subtractor object
background_subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(2000)

# Parameters for blob detection
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 100  # Minimum area of particles
params.maxArea = 500  # Maximum area of particles

# Create a blob detector with the specified parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Create video writer
output_filename = 'output_video.mp4'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # Codec for the output video
output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

# Process each frame
frame_number = 1
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    frame1 = frame

    # Do hough transform
    frame_copy = cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (5, 5), 0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame_copy, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT, dp=1, minDist=5,
                               param1=100, param2=0.5, minRadius=20, maxRadius=30)
    
    if circles is not None:
        # Convert the coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        
        # Loop over the detected circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # Draw the circle on the original image
            cv2.circle(frame1, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 1)

    # Display the result
    cv2.putText(frame1, f"Frame: {frame_number}", (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Particle Detection', frame1)

    # Write the frame to the output video
    output_video.write(frame1)

    frame_number += 1

    # Break the loop if 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture and video writer
video.release()
output_video.release()

# Close windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: yeah, you need proper tracking, at least for a short distance (hysteresis on that cut plane). Hough may help with detection but that's all. it's very noisy. also, your spheres overlap and occlude each other. that's a problem. how exact does the detection and tracking have to be? how much effort would you expend on the physical (cameras) side?